# Should I compress images in java backend before sending to frontend?

Tags: java, image, frontend, compression, backend

I am developing a project where we have a Java Spring backend server connecting with a front-end page through endpoints.

At the moment in one of our endpoints we are sending an image url to be represented in the frontend. Currently we can see some performance issues on the frontend when loading the images as the sizes vary quite a lot and some are quite big. In order to try and solve this I am checking how to compress the image in the backend in order to be easier for the front end to represent them. However, during my investigation I also noticed that there are a lot of tools to compress images in the front end directly.

My question is: Should I compress them in the backend (will include downloading the image + compressing it into a new file + sending it to frontend + deleting the file) or should it be done by the frontend?

Comment: What would be the point of compressing it in the front end?

Comment: Do you mean [data compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_compression) for faster network transmission, or do you mean reduce image size/quality?

Comment: yeh the point would be more on the image size in order to not take so much time rendering it in the front end page

Comment: images are generally transferred as jpg, png, gif, or webm. These are already highly compressed formats; most of these will get __zero__ compression if you toss them to a general purpose compressor such as `zip` or `gz` or even `7zip` or whatnot. `bmp` and `tiff` are non-compressed formats. They are.. not even compatible with web browsers. So, what are you talking about? Take a large image, resample it to be tiny? Yeah that'll help, a ton. But it also makes the picture look really bad. Same idea with taking a `jpg`, reducing its quality.